# Distinguish between text and checkbox in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert my table to html. I am trying to derive the data from the `input text fields` and not from the `input checkbox fields`
The following is my javascript code as can be seen in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4UQf/27/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hello').click(function(e) {     
var array = [];
var headers = [];
$('#my_table tr:first-child td').each(function(index, item) {
    headers[index] = $('> input[type="text"]', item).val();
});
$.each(headers, function(index, item) {
        var name=item;
    var data =[];
    $('#my_table tr:first-child').nextAll().each(function() {
        $('td:nth-child('+(index+1)+')', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
            data.push(parseInt($('> input[type="text"]', item).val()));
        });
        });
    array.push({name: name, data:data});
    });
  var categories=array[0].data;
  alert(categories);
  array.shift();
                var chart= new Highcharts.Chart({ chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
     },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: array
        });
        });
        });
```

My code is supposed to take the first column as the xaxis. For this it is supposed to skip the checkbox column. However, the jquery selector does not appear to distinguish between both types of inputs and skip the column type. What am I supposed to do differently to achieve what I intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main causes for this:

- In the loop where you build the header you don't filter out the first column. True, the `input[type="text"]` selector will not give a result for the first column, but it still generates an entry in the `headers` array. Instead, move that `input` selector into the main selector so that you don't even visit the first column
- In the loop where you build the `array` variable, you access the `td` by the selector `td:nth-child('+(index+1)+')'`, but since the `index` values start at 0, you'll be accessing child number 1, which still is the first column. So you need to write `index+2` in there.

With some other improvements (the use of `map` is useful for generating arrays), the following code could be used:

```
    var headers = $('#my_table tr:first-child input[type="text"]').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    var array = $.map(headers, function(item, index) {
        var name = item;
        var data = $('#my_table tr td:nth-child('+(index+2)+') input[type="text"]')
            // slice(1) will skip the first row (alternative to your method)
            .slice(1).map(function() {
                return +($(this).val()); // unitary + will do number conversion
            }).get();
        return {name: name, data: data};
    });
    var categories = array.shift().data;
    var chart= new Highcharts.Chart({ chart: {
        // ... etc.
```

After entering some input in [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4UQf/28/), I got this result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain what exactly you want to get with sample input and an image of the output. I added a screenshot of the input/output I used to test the solution I provided. Can you clarify?